# How to delete a tagged release of a Go module

Tags: git, go, tags

Deleted (locally and remotely) tag for a git repository.

```
git tag -d v13.0.0
git push origin :refs/tags/v13.0.0
```

I had created tag v13.0.0 and then deleted.

But still I can do `go get github.com/IBM/nzgo@v13.0.0`

Do I need to delete it any other way?

I can see there is no v13.0.0 tag here:
https://github.com/IBM/nzgo/tags

Comment: `go get` obtains tag-to-hash-ID translations and then *keeps them*. Deleting the tag (or changing it) doesn't alter the cached translation. (This is one of many reasons that Git tags should never be changed: it just doesn't *work*.)

Comment: Thanks @torek. Is there any way we can get list of such tags, deleted ones but available in go get?

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-cache - I have not used this a lot, but it's clear that the big Brute Force Hammer is `go clean -modcache` and `go mod verify` *might* be better for this (having not tried it, I don't know).

Answer (score 2):

Published modules can not be deleted but only be retracted. Please have a look at this on how to retract a version. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68599844/8386079).

From [documentation](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes#TOC_5.)

> To keep module builds deterministic, a version cannot be modified
> after it is published. Even if you delete or change a version tag,
> proxy.golang.org and other proxies probably already have the original
> cached.

Also, Retracted versions should remain available in version control repositories and on module proxies to ensure that builds that depend on them are not broken.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60119326/8386079) by icza gives alternate way of sending an email to `go-discovery-feedback@google.com`, with the import path or module path that you want to remove might help too.